# HTML and CSS: Float a block element inside another block element?

Tags: css, html, web, css-float

Is it possible to float a `<ul>` inside a `<div>`? If so, how?

Comment: Why not?  Just set the `float` css property on the `ul` element.

Comment: To understand what's going on when trying something new, I temporarily set "border:" with a different color on each element that may be involved in the layout (in this case at least both the <ul> and the <div>, and probably the <div>s parent and the first <li> too).

Comment: A bit more than 4 years later, now with a lot more experience, I wonder why I didn't just try floating the `<ul>` inside the `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[YES]

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.my-div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  div.my-div ul.left-floated {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    /* display: block; */
  }
  div.my-div ul.right-floated {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    /* display: block; */
  }
  .clearfix {
    clear: both;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="my-div">
  <ul class="left-floated">
  </ul>

  <ul class="right-floated">
  </ul>

  <br class="clearfix" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want:

```
div > ul
{
    float: left;
}
```